# HCS clustering throwing function ‘nodes’ for signature ‘"numeric"’ error

Tags: r, parallel-processing

`#Loading libraries`

`library(GraphClusterAnalysis)
library(igraph)
library(RBGL)
library(graph)
library(snow)
library(snowfall)
library(parallel)`

## reading Input data

`data<-read.csv('/home/poorna/Desktop/Cluster/test',header=FALSE,sep=",")
G = graph.data.frame(data,directed=FALSE)`

## make cluster type

`cl <- makeCluster( '172.1.30.240', type="SOCK" )
clusterExport(cl, c('data'))`

## HCS cluster in parallel

`results <- parLapply( cl, G, function(G) {
require(GraphClusterAnalysis)
require(igraph)
require(RBGL)
HCSClustering(G,kappa=3)
} )`

I try to execute the above code in parallel but its throwing a below error`

Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  one node produced an error: unable to find an inherited method for function ‘nodes’ for signature ‘"numeric"’`

## my Input data is in below format

`2,5
159,5
2,100
2,858
3,100`

Comment: Does the code run in single thread mode? You could try by exporting the necessary libraries to all the nodes instead of calling them in function definition.

Comment: Yes, single thread mode(sequential mode) will run fine. the code for the single thread mode as below:                                                                                      HCS_Example<-read.csv('/home/poorna/Desktop/Cluster/test',fill=TRUE,header=FALSE)
G = graph.data.frame(HCS_Example,directed=FALSE)

HCSClustering(G,kappa=3)

Comment: Where you get the GraphClusterAnalysis library ????