# "GraphClusterAnalysis" package in R

Tags: r

Please, how can I get "GraphClusterAnalysis" package installed? I am trying to use the "Highly connected sub graphs" (HCS) clustering algorithm for my data. I have tried to use install.packages() for the installation but I keep getting: package ‘GraphClusterAnalysis’ is not available (for R version 3.0.3).

Comment: What makes you think this package exists? Upon cursory look at the google, nothing close to this comes up.

Comment: It was mentioned in : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093381/hcs-clustering-throwing-function-nodes-for-signature-numeric-error/45484542#45484542          Notes on Graph clustering also mentioned it as a package that contains HCS clustering and other graph clustering techniques:  https://www.csc2.ncsu.edu/faculty/nfsamato/practical-graph-mining-with-R/slides/pdf/Graph_Cluster_Analysis.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use a method called "highlyConnSG()" for the HCS clustering algorithm which I retrieved after installing "RGBL" and "graph" packages from source "https://biconductor.org/bioLite.R". So to install those packages, type in the R environment command line:

> *source("https://biconductor.org/biocLite.R")*
>
> *biocLite("RBGL")*
>
> *biocLite("graph")*

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see, this is a library, written by the authors of the book ( https://www.csc2.ncsu.edu/faculty/nfsamato/practical-graph-mining-with-R/PracticalGraphMiningWithR.html ).

Also on this page is provided the link to the archive with this library itself (here is the link: https://www.csc2.ncsu.edu/faculty/nfsamato/practical-graph-mining-with-R/R-code/GraphClusterAnalysis.zip ).

So you can load this library and after that you can try to install the library from source. Here is the stackoverflow question about how to do it:
 [How do I install an R package from source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474081/how-do-i-install-an-r-package-from-source)

Nevertheless, as for me I wasn't successful in installing it from source.